# RethinkDB Map/Reduce examples

Tags: rethinkdb

I running through the Map/Reduce examples in the RethinkDB docs. I have some documents that look like this:

```
{
"category":  "Fiction" ,
"content":  "This far, no further!" ,
"id":  "0fc5339b-8139-4996-8979-88a0051195e3" ,
"title":  "The line must be drawn here"
}
```

When I follow the examples using Data Explorer. e.g.

```
r.table('posts').map(lambda post: 1)
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Data Explorer only allows JavaScript as an input. You need to switch to something like this to make it work:

```
r.table('posts').map(function(post){return 1})
```